# Why do I get a blank MAC address?

Tags: java, networking, mac-address

The following program is meant to print the MAC address of my node. But it prints a blank. I checked it for null but it isn't null. Why would I get a blank MAC address ? What mistake am I committing ?

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;

class Tester {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
      byte mac[] = ni.getHardwareAddress();
      if(mac == null) {
        System.out.println("Mac address is null");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Else block!");
        String macAdd = new String(mac);
        System.out.println(macAdd);
      }

    } catch(Exception exc) {
       exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

***Note:*** `mac == null` is false.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4634398), *"Well, the interface that reacts to "localhost" is usually the loopback device, which doesn't have a MAC address, so that might be your reason."*

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a `localhost` loop back interface with a MAC address. I suspect it's not very useful.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mac));
```

prints

```
[]
```

which is not surprising as its only a virtual software device.

Comment: If I replace `localhost` with my network IP `192.168.43.187` I get to see this : `p±íí▀⌡` What is it ?

Comment: Its your mac address turned characters. If you know the ascii codes of those characters you can work out the mac address or you can print it the way I suggested if you want to see the numbers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should get localhost by `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` instead of `InetAddress.getByName("localhost");`.Please refer my below example for the solution of your problem.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
            byte mac[] = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac == null) {
                System.out.println("Mac address is null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Else block!");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
                }
                String macAdd = new String(sb);
                System.out.println(macAdd);
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Else block!
44-87-FC-F1-D4-77
```

**NOTE :-**

Remember that it is important to convert the mac address recieved into readable hexadecimal format, so I have written the below code block. If you dont do that then you will received garbage text as `D‡üñÔw`.

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }
            String macAdd = new String(sb);
```

Comment: can you please explain me the step `String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "")`

Comment: This is called to format your MAC address received into readable HEX format, if you dont do this then your output would be `D‡üñÔw` like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JavaDocs](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName) for Java 7, you will notice there's the `getLocalhost()` which is what you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address is an array of bytes, the first of which may be zero.

To print it you need to convert it to a printable, alphanumeric (e.g. hexadecimal) format, for example using String.format as shown in [Bhavik Ambani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817065/49942).